# Riverpod - ref.refresh. The value of 'refresh' should be used

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I'm using riverpod with flutter.

On my main screen I have a FutureProvider which makes a call to the API server, and displays results on the page.

At various points in the app, the user on different screens, makes changes, and I refresh the provider from the other screen. Like this

```
ref.refresh(calendarResponseProvider);
```

Now, for some reason, the refresh is in grey, and I get this error:

[image]

Now, I am using the value of refresh on the other screen. Am I doing something wrong? Should I ignore it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you do not use the result returned by `refresh()`, then use the `invalidate()` method to reset the provider state.

Writing:

```dart
final newValue = ref.refresh(provider);
```

is strictly identical to doing:

```dart
ref.invalidate(provider);
final newValue = ref.read(provider);
```