# Riverpod, how to pass different values to a database

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

I was trying to build a search bar and every time the value of the search bar changed I want to pass the value to the database function which searches the db according to the value of the search bar. The problem is when I use `FutureProvider.family` so that I can pass it an argument, and when `ref.refresh(searchResultsProvider(query))` is called within the `onChanged`, the `ref.watch(searchResultsProvider(''))` can trigger a rebuild of the widget, but it is not working, it **only** rebuilds the widget if the same string parameter is passed to the provider, But I want to pass different string arguments every time onChanged is called.

The **provider**:

```
final searchResultsProvider = FutureProvider.autoDispose
    .family<List<Map<String, dynamic>>, String>((ref, value) async {
  final data = await dbGetSearchResults(value);

  return data;
});
```

**.watch**:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final searchResults = ref.watch(searchResultsProvider(''));
```

**onChanged**:

```
TextField(onChanged: (value) {
                    ref.refresh(searchResultsProvider(value));
                  },
```

Comment: You may want to check if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75553329/6919963) doesn't solve your issue. Looks like you may need to invalidate the provider since you're not using the return of it anyway.

Comment: @MiguelRuivo tried invalidate, it acts the same

Comment: You don't refresh a provider you are no longer using!  You make those autodispose, and then when you change search terms, you're effectively watching a *different* provider.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding another provider, which will be responsible for the state of the text box:

```dart
final textFieldValue = StateProvider((_) => '');
```

Then in the widget you can do this:

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final fieldValue = ref.watch(textFieldValue);
  final searchResults = ref.watch(searchResultsProvider(fieldValue));

  ...
  TextField(
    onChanged: (value) {
      ref.read(textFieldValue.notifier).update((_) => value);
    },
```

Every time the value of the `textFieldValue` provider changes, the `searchResultsProvider(fieldValue)` query with the new parameter will take place.